# Change Magento 2 website based on IP

Tags: magento2, php, api, curl, index.php

I have 3 websites in my current Magento installation and are as follows website1 `Code: base`, website2 `Code: au`, website3 `Code: ca`. Each website has one `store` and one `store_view` except for website3 which has 2 `store-views`.

I want the users to be automatically navigated to a specific website based on their country. For example, all users with the country code `US` to be navigated to website1.

I have checked that [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/developers) provides country code through an API call as follow

```
# Get country ISO code as plaintext
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/country?token=$TOKEN
US
```

Can anyone help with its implementation for my Magento 2.2.6 instance?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, I'm using geoplugin to get the country of my customers ip address. I also have a cookie just in case the customer after being redirected to a store let's say in Portuguese actually prefers to use the English version, I store a value in the cookie so the customer doesn't get redirected back to the Portuguese version. Let me know if you need any further assistance and don't forget to upvote / mark as answer if this solved your problem :)

In your **etc\events.xml**

```
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch">
        <observer name="controller_action_postdispatch" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\PostDespatchEvent" />
    </event>
```

In your **Vendor\Module\Observer\PostDespatchEvent.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

class PostDespatchEvent implements ObserverInterface
{  

    /**
     * Name of Cookie that holds private content version
     */
    CONST COOKIE_NAME = 'COOKIE_DEFAULT_LANG_CUSTOM';

    /**
     * Cookie life time
     */
    CONST COOKIE_LIFE = 3600;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
     */


    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $cookieManager;
    protected $cookieMetadataFactory;
    private   $scopeConfigInterface;

    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $cart;
    protected $customerSession;
    
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface                           $storeManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface                            $scopeConfigInterface,
        CookieManagerInterface                          $cookieManager,
        CookieMetadataFactory                           $cookieMetadataFactory,
        SessionManagerInterface                         $sessionManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session                 $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart                    $cart,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session                 $customerSession
        
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfigInterface = $scopeConfigInterface;
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;

        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart            = $cart;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function getCookie($name)
    {
        return $this->cookieManager->getCookie($name);
    }
    public function setCookie($value, $duration = 604800)
    {
        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration($duration)
            ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME, $value, $metadata);

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $cookie = self::getCookie(SELF::COOKIE_NAME);
        if(!isset( $cookie))
        {
            $countryCode = SELF::ip_info("Visitor", "Country Code"); 

            if($countryCode == 'PT')
            {            
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('default');                
            }
            else
            {
                if($countryCode == 'DE')
                {            
                    $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('DE');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('EN');
                }
           }

             self::setCookie( SELF::COOKIE_NAME);
        }
    }

    public static function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
        $output = NULL;
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            if ($deep_detect) {
                if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }
        }
        $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
        $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
        $continents = array(
            "AF" => "Africa",
            "AN" => "Antarctica",
            "AS" => "Asia",
            "EU" => "Europe",
            "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
            "NA" => "North America",
            "SA" => "South America"
        );
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
            $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp"));
            if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
                switch ($purpose) {
                    case "location":
                        $output = array(
                            "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                            "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                            "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                            "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                            "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                            "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                        );
                        break;
                    case "address":
                        $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                        if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                            $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                        if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                            $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                        $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                        break;
                    case "city":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                        break;
                    case "state":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                        break;
                    case "region":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                        break;
                    case "country":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                        break;
                    case "countrycode":
                        $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: 1: I have created and registered a module, and then created events.xml under /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Zazai/Module/etc/events.xml.

2: I have created PostDespatchEvent.php file under /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Zazai/Module/Observer/PostDespatchEvent.php

3: I have replaced the term Vendor with Zazai in both the files

4: I have changed 'PT' and 'default'
    if($countryCode == 'PT')
            {            
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore('default');
           }
according to the 'country code' and 'store code' I wanted navigation for.

Comment: But the solution didn't work yet.

Comment: Please make sure you run the following commands:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

Also you can use Xdebug to check if the observer is running. Let me know what error it is throwing so I can help

Comment: is it working? What are you using to "emulate" different website calls to test this out?

Comment: $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp"));
May I know why you are not passing the user IP address because by default http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp will take the server IP address and return the country where the website is hosted not the user country.

Comment: I have added ?ip=$ip to  $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=$ip")); now the variable $countryCode has the country of the user, not the server, but there is one more issue if a user1 access the website with his country code the US after a cache flush, the store-view US will be displayed to that and every other user from the cache and the event will not be triggered again even if the user2 has country code DE.

Comment: since you already worked much through this, I would recommend taking a look at this example https://github.com/princefishthrower/example-magento-2-geo-ip-redirect
and this https://github.com/princefishthrower/example-magento-2-geo-ip-redirect/blob/6b8b8d95fef982fb9bfe7839ed37f3144612c9a0/YourCompany/YourModule/Service/GelocationService.php#L68